# How to add class based on which css class name is come in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have two buttons with text saying day and night, now i want to apply the css class onclick on the basis of which button is clicked

this is my html

```
<div class="container">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">day</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">night</button>
</div>
```

and this is my jquery

```
<script>  

    $(function () {
        $('button').click(function () {
            var buttonName = $(this).text().toLocaleLowerCase;
            console.log(buttonName);
            $('div').attr('button', buttonName + '.Class');
        });
    });        
</script>
```

please help me to run this code
i have trouble with this line 
$('div').attr('button', buttonName + '.Class');
where code will decide which cssClass needs to be load on button when click event fired.

Comment: `$('div').attr('button'...`?? Really?? `button` is **not** an attribute of `div`. It is a child / descendant element.

Comment: $(this).addClass(buttonName);

Comment: you didn't have to -1 him though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give Ids to the button, and on that give click function

**JSBIN link** http://jsbin.com/femabeqedo/1/edit

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <button id="btnDay" class="btn btn-primary">day</button>
    <button id="btnNight" class="btn btn-primary">night</button>
</div>
```

**Java Script**

```
<script>

    $(function () {
        $('#btnDay').click(function () {
            $('body').removeClass("night");
            $('body').addClass("day");

        });

      $('#btnNight').click(function () {
            $('body').removeClass("day");
            $('body').addClass("night");
        });
    });   
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(this).addClass('classname');
```

"this" refers to the exact element that triggered the click.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is what you wanted.

Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kornezz/sLbooh3t/3/) it add class to div of selected button.

HTML

```
div class="container">     
<button class="btn btn-primary" value="day">day</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" value="night">night</button> 
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(function () {
    TempButtonName = '';
        $('button').click(function () {
            $('div').removeClass(TempButtonName );
            var buttonName = $(this).val();
            console.log(buttonName);
            $('div').addClass(buttonName);
            TempButtonName = buttonName;
        });
  });
```